# How to handle a variable being used by 2 threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

One thread keeps reading bytes received from a `BufferedReader`. The data comes from a `SerialPort`.

On the main thread, there is a `JMenuItem` when it's clicked the serial port is closed and the BufferedReader should stop receiving the messages.

The problem is:

If I try to close while messages are being read, the application will stuck and the serial port won't be closed until the port stops sending messages.

So basically, I should close the reader before closing the serial port. If I do this, sometimes I get a null pointer exception because I close the buffered reader while he is being read.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you care about what the `BufferedReader` is reading when you close it for the `JMenuItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can fix this with a `stop` method in your reader class (called from the menu item's `click` event)

```
private boolean isStopped = false;

public void stop() {
    isStopped = true;
}

while(bufferedReader.isReady()) {
    bufferedReader.read();
    if(isStopped) {
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

This way you ensure that you don't call `close` until all `read` calls have completed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to create a SynchronizedReader class which would wrap your `BufferedReader`. But without more context, I cannot guarantee this will work, especially if you have calling code which makes multiple interdependent calls to the `Reader` (you would then need to ensure that all calls are made in a single `synchronized(reader)` block).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

public class SynchronizedReader extends Reader {

    private Reader reader;

    public SynchronizedReader(Reader reader) {
        super();
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        return reader.read(cbuf, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        reader.close();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int hashCode() {
        return reader.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int read(CharBuffer target) throws IOException {
        return reader.read(target);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int read() throws IOException {
        return reader.read();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int read(char[] cbuf) throws IOException {
        return reader.read(cbuf);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return reader.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        return reader.skip(n);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean ready() throws IOException {
        return reader.ready();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean markSupported() {
        return reader.markSupported();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void mark(int readAheadLimit) throws IOException {
        reader.mark(readAheadLimit);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
        reader.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized String toString() {
        return reader.toString();
    }

}
```